# bash - How to find string from file and get its position?

Tags: string, bash, find

File `services` - contains many records like this one:

```
define service {
    host_name\t\t\t\tHOSTNAME
    ...
    ...
}
```

File `hosts` - contains records:

```
define host {
    host_name\t\t\t\tHOSTNAME
    ...
    ...
}
```

and I need to go to `hosts`, somehow get name of HOSTNAME from first record, then go to file `services` and find all records with that HOSTNAME and put them to other file. Then do it for every HOSTNAME in `hosts`.

What I don't know is primary how to get the HOSTNAME from file hosts and then how to get a whole record in file services to a variable. I have prepared a regex (hope it's right) `^define.*host_name\t\t\t\t$HOSTNAME.*}`

Please give me a few advices or examples how to get wanted result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This task a bit too complex for a bash script. I would use Perl:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $SRV, '<', 'services' or die $!;
open my $HST, '<', 'hosts'    or die $!;

my %services;
{    local $/ = "\n}";
     while (my $service = <$SRV>) {
         my ($hostname) = $service =~ /^\s*host_name\t+(.+?)\s*$/m;
         push @{ $services{$hostname} }, $service if defined $hostname;
     }
 }

while (my $line = <$HST>) {
    if (my ($host) = $line =~ /^\s*host_name\t+(.+?)\s*$/) {
        if (exists $services{$host}) {
            print "===== $host =====\n";
            print "$_\n" for @{ $services{$host} };
        } else {
            warn "$host not found in services!\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The files you provide look very much like nagios configuration files.

sed might be your friend here, as it allows you to slice the file into smaller parts, eg:

```
:t
/^define service {/,/}$/ {    # For each line between these block markers..
   /}$/!{         #   If we are not at the /end/ marker
      $!{          #     nor the last line of the file,
         N;        #     add the Next line to the pattern space
         bt
      }            #   branch (loop back) to the :t label.
   }               # This line matches the /end/ marker.
   /host_name[ \t]\+HOSTNAME\b/!d;       # delete the block if wrong host.
}
```

That example lifted from the sed faq 4.21, and adapted slightly. You could also look at question 4.22 which appears to address this directly:

http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq4.html#s4.22

Like the previous answer, I'm also inclined to say you're probably better off using another scripting language. If you need a different interpreter to get this done anyway, might as well use something you know.